# Cast tuples inside list to int

Tags: python, list, int, tuples

How would one go about turning a list with tuples inside it, in the form of,

```
list = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]
```

into a list with ints in it, like,

```
list = [197, 156, 17, 14, 74, 7]
```

in the most efficient way possible? I've tried with recursion but it's too memory expensive for large lists (thousands of tuples).

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for converting every tuple:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> l = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, t) for t in l]
[197, 156, 17, 14, 74, 7]
```

**Update** Since question was asking for efficient method here are measurements for suggested answers:

```
import itertools as it
import functools

def conv_reduce(l):
    return [functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, t) for t in l]

def conv_str(l):
    return [int("".join(map(str, item))) for item in l]

def conv_pow(l):
    return [sum(n*10**e for n, e in zip(reversed(item), it.count())) for item in l]

def conv_pow2(l):
    return [sum(t[-i-1]*(10**i) for i in range(len(t))) for t in l]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print('reduce', timeit.timeit("conv_reduce(l)", setup="from __main__ import conv_reduce; l = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]"))
    print('str', timeit.timeit("conv_str(l)", setup="from __main__ import conv_str; l = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]"))
    print('pow', timeit.timeit("conv_pow(l)", setup="from __main__ import conv_pow; l = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]"))
    print('pow2', timeit.timeit("conv_pow2(l)", setup="from __main__ import conv_pow2; l = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]"))
```

Output:

```
reduce 2.5965667460041004
str 5.068828338997264
pow 7.192991987001733
pow2 8.017168823003885
```

Comment: It will be great if you could add the execution time of [my function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41734122/2063361). Why to ignore one :P

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Added your suggestion as pow2, I decided to initially exclude it because one of the other suggestions had the same principle so I didn't assume big difference in performance.

Answer (score 2):

One way to approach the problem is to cast to string each of the integers in sublists, join and convert to `int`:

```
In [1]: l = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]

In [2]: [int("".join(map(str, item))) for item in l]
Out[2]: [197, 156, 17, 14, 74, 7]
```

Or, using the power of tens (a variation of already posted answer by @AChampion):

```
In [3]: [sum(10 ** index * value for index, value in enumerate(reversed(item))) 
         for item in l]
Out[3]: [197, 156, 17, 14, 74, 7]
```

Comment: @AChampion thanks, I'm pretty sure there is an efficient numpy solution there as well..

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively simple to convert a list of digits to a number. Convert them to strings `join()` and convert back to `int`. Or you can do it more mathematically:

```
>>> [sum(n*10**e for e, n in enumerate(reversed(item))) for item in l]
[197, 156, 17, 14, 74, 7]
```

Note: don't use `list` as a variable name as this will hide the python `list` type.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use little bit of mathematics to achieve this. Here I am multiplying the digits in tuple with power of `10` in reverse order to get the number.

```
>>> my_list = list = [(1, 9, 7), (1, 5, 6), (1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4), (7,)]

#     v sum numbers based on their position at hundred, tens, ones place  
>>> [sum(t[-i-1]*(10**i) for i in range(len(t))) for t in my_list]
[197, 156, 17, 14, 74, 7]
```